# Как выводить результаты ping в qtablewidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import subprocess, os, threading, time
from queue import Queue


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(371, 626)
        self.formLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(Form)
        self.formLayout_2.setObjectName("formLayout_2")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.formLayout_2.setLayout(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.formLayout)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 600))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.tableWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "host ip"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "ping"))

lock = threading.Lock()
_start = time.time()

# Пример ip адреса:
eq_ip_start = '10.69.0.'


def check(n):
    # Configure subprocess to hide the console window
    info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
    with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
                ip = str(eq_ip_start) + "{0}".format(n)
                output = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '500', ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=info).communicate()[0]
                result_ping = list(output.strip().decode('cp866').split('\n'))
                all_time_ms = list(result_ping[-1].split(','))
                medium_time_ms = list(all_time_ms[-1].split(' '))
                with lock:
                    if "Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса" in output.decode('cp866'):
                        eq_status = 'Offline'
                        print (ip, "Offline")
                    else:
                        eq_status = medium_time_ms[3]
                        print(ip, eq_status)
    return eq_status

def threader():
    while True:
        worker=q.get()
        check(worker)
        q.task_done()
q = Queue()

def start_ping():
    for x in range(255):
        t = threading.Thread(target=threader)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for worker in range(1, 255):
        q.put(worker)
    q.join()
    print("Все потоки выполнены за: ",time.time()-_start)

start_ping()
# Запуск каждые 10 секунд:
threading.Timer(5, start_ping).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: И в чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: Как выводить результаты ping в форму с qtablewidget? Заранее Спасибо

Comment: Вы привели код, что с ним? Он не работает, не выводит то что должен, или вы просто не знаете что с кодом сделать, чтобы он выводил то что нужно?